# Goole Sheets - Formula for converting UTC date and time using multiple text criteria

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a multiple criteria function that will help convert date and time based on a text criteria.

If cell A = “SF” then convert time using this calculation =LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"T"," "),19) - 7/24

If cell A = “NY” then convert time using this calculation =LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B3,"T"," "),19) - 4/24

If cell A = “Online” use the same UTC time in column B

If cell A = “ - ” use the same UTC time in column B

Comment: Here is my google sheet with my table for reference. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rZJo9uB806qO7dvsCuLmX46grO3bBS7_LtowtM7aFYA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a converstion table on a side and use vlookup formula for searching the table:

IN C2

```
=ArrayFormula(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"T"," "),19) + vlookup(A2:A5,E2:F18,2,false)/24)
```

[image]

You can also add IFNA formula around VLOOKUP to add 0 whenever value in column A is not found in conversion table.

Like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"T"," "),19) + ifna(vlookup(A2:A5,E2:F18,2,false),0)/24)
```

Comment: Worked perfect and it makes complete sense now. I didn't even think about adding a lookup table.